# Need an alternative to sumifs()/sum(filter())/sumproduct() to increase performance

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas, excel-365

I have a sheet with several columns. The rows could go up to the 10s of thousands. Some of the rows are subtotals from the rows below. I have an automated index that works like below:

```
i
i.i
i.i.i
i.i.j
j
j.i
j.j
```

i is a subtotal of all i.x items, while i.i is a subtotal of all i.i.x items and so on.

The lowerest indexes are always items, which have their own value.

Problem is, as the sheet is filled and rows are added, it goes slower to the point of becoming unusable.

[link to the desensitized sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RPasB4TS_S3EzCh8JhVeDdfuRRyRTpso/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=117814412846698716615&rtpof=true&sd=true)
*open in excel, there are named formulas that won't open on google sheets.

What consumes processing power is the subtotals. So far, I have used both: sumifs(), sum(filter()), sumproduct(), sum({array}*{array}), to automatically calculate de subtotals, and the performance is bad on all options.

I realize that using a regular subtotal() would cut processing consumption, but, in the other hand, when new rows are added in the middle of the sheet, it requires a lot of adjustments to fix the ranges that need to be summed. Oftenly, my team make some mistake into adjusting the ranges, resulting in wrong subtotals and having a hard time finding it later, consuming a lot of worktime

Pivot table is not an option, nor the group subtotals, since I need to follow the structure and formatting of the original sheet.

Do you guys have any idea on how to do this in a better way?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Consider using Manual Calculation, add the rows you need and then recalculate everything just once. Notice that everytime you modify something, Excel recalculates everything by default. Manual calculation avoids this and sometimes it's helpful. Anyways, without looking at your data, if you have thousands of rows it looks like you are using Excel as a database and Excel **is not** good for databases. Consider migrating data to databases. . Check https://officemastery.com/_automatic-vs-manual-calculations-in-excel

Comment: Well, for starters, use `=TEXTJOIN(".",1,IF(A3:H3>0,A3:H3,""))` in `I3`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Thanks for the welcome! It's not a database. It's a budget sheet, but our budgets are really detailed and can get really long.

Comment: Would you have the **exact** formulas you tried? Just naming the functions does not cut it.

Comment: From the desensitized sheet (I hope I translated the functions correctly): `=SUM(FILTER(O$2:O$465;(LEFT($I$2:$I$465;LEN($I2))=$I2)*($J$2:$J$465<>0)*ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT($I$2:$I$465;1)));0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need *alternative* functions; you simply need to reduce the number of redundant calculations:
looking at row 7, the filters in cells `O7:R7` are *all* filtering on the *same* criteria (which are calculated, afresh, for each filter), so instead of 4 separate (but related, since they all use the same criteria) filters, you could simply write the formula below

```
=LET(net,FILTER(O$2:R$465,(LEFT($I$2:$I$465,LEN($I7)+1)=$I7&".")*($J$2:$J$465<>0)*ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT($I$2:$I$465,1))),0),MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(net),1,0),net))
```

(i.e. apply a *single* filter, *once*, to the 4-column range, and generate a sum for each column)

in cell `O7`, and see that it generates the same totals

similarly (still on row 7), all of the filters in cells `X7:GI7` are also using the *same* criteria (i.e. the same criteria being calculated 168 times(!)), such that you could write the formula below

```
=LET(net,N(FILTER(X$2:GI$465,(LEFT($I$2:$I$465,LEN($I7)+1)=$I7&".")*($J$2:$J$465<>0),0)),MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(net),1,0),net))
```

(again, a *single* filter, *once*, of a multi-column range, calculating a sum for each column)

in cell `X7` and eliminate the redundant calculations from `X7:GI7`

Making these updates will result in 170 fewer uses of the `FILTER()` function, *per sub-total row* (together with no-longer duplicated criteria calculations) so I anticipate that this will improve performance to some extent.